# How to make body take 100% min height and height as auto

Tags: html, css

On my page, I want to make the body be at least 100% of the viewport (i.e. when the content is very less) but take on the height of the content as content increases.

Right now I have done

```
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;}
```

But with this, if the content increases, then body remains 100% of viewport height only and does not take the height of the content.

How to solve for this?

Comment: How can you tell? Do you have a background color set or something? The body is generally always 100%.

Comment: I have a box shadow on the body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`body { min-height: 100vh; }` is all you'll need.

Comment: this may have issues with mobile

Comment: Not "may", you'll have a lot of problems. Especially if you try to make a fullscreen experience like a game. https://nicolas-hoizey.com/articles/2015/02/18/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers/

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    min-height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

This should be work.

Answer (score 1):

1. What you can do with css is to use “vw” unit. Just set body’s , width, height, min-width and min-height to 100vw/vh correspondingly; also you can give “box-sizing” : “border-box” which should include margin and paddings in the width and height 
   2.If you are not happy with the css results, you can always use javascript. You must write a function which will give viewport width and viewport height to body’s with and height,
   With jquery you can do it like

$( window ).width();//documents width
$( document).width();//documents width

Same should work with height, call this function when document is ready

Comment: JavaScript now not necessary at all. Setting the height to 100vw is certainly not what you want either.

Comment: You vw it always works because 100vw is the full width of your screen and 100vh is the full height of your screen, I.e. viewport width and viewport height

Comment: No, you said to set the height to 100vw. That is viewports widths, not heights. It's no the same thing.

Comment: You should set the width to 100vw and height to 100vh (viewport height)